# Replication of Stata commnad in R

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, fixed-effects-model, clustered-standard-errors

I am not very good at working in R, usually I am working with stata. I just need to replicate one study in R. 
The command, which I need to replicate from Stata is :

```
logit y x z v l m i.year, cl(name) nolog
```

I have tried to use in R command :

```
install.packages("miceadds")
install.packages("multiwayvcov")
library(miceadds)
library("multiwayvcov")
reg2 <- miceadds::glm.cluster( data=data, formula=y~x+z+v+l+m +factor(year),
                cluster="name", family="binomial")
```

This gave me the same coefficients as well as Standard errors like Stata, but the z-value and p-value were absolutely different, what meant that the variables were not statistically significant.

Also I have tried to run command

```
logit<glm(y~x+z+v+l+m +factor(year),
  data = data, family="binomial" (link=logit))
```

But I do not know how to cluster the standard errors in this case.
Can anyone help me how to run a logistic regression where will be the year fixed and also, I will be able to cluster standard errors?

Comment: Sorry the second command does not appear. It is logit<-glm(y~x+z+v+l+m +factor(year), data = data, family="binomial" (link=logit))

Comment: By assuming your readers are fluent both in `R` and `Stata`, you are limiting your audience to a small number.  If you would explain what the Stata command is supposed to do, you would make your question accessible to a vastly larger audience and thereby improve the chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: stata does not entirely document what the `cluster` option of `logit` does. As far as I can see, the stata documentation does not cite a published paper describing the statistical method that has been implemented, so it could be that the calculation is specific to stata and can't be reproduced exactly in R.